# javascript calling

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I'm calling this function from .cs file what is wrong

```
function Confirmcertificate(){

    var agree=confirm("Not sending any certificate");

    if(agree)

         return true;

         onsubmit: true;

    else
         return false;

          onsubmit: false;
}
```

.cs file coding is

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), 
"load","Confirmcertificate();", true);
```

Comment: Is the function being fired at all? Is that code working?
Try: `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(),"load","alert('Hello world';", true);`

Comment: if/else without curly braces is asking for trouble...not sure what "onsubmit:" is supposed to do after a return statement...and you will need to provide a more specific question than "what is wrong".

Comment: Please explain exactly what you're trying to achieve here. Apart from your syntactical issues, it looks like you're trying to prevent form submission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the line after returning true and false

```
  onsubmit: true;


  onsubmit: false;
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the lines:

```
onsubmit: true;
```

and

```
onsubmit: false;
```

That's not valid Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Several problems:

```
function Confirmcertificate(){    
    if(confirm("Not sending any certificate"))
    { // you need braces to encapsulate multiple statements 
         onsubmit = true; // I imagine you meant to assign to some global variable...
         return true; // This must come after the assignment 
    } else {
         onsubmit = false; // this must come before return
         return false;    
    }
}
```

With those changes it should work.